# Search a PDF file and copy to the folder

Tags: excel, vba

In an Excel table, I have 10 file names like:
test1, test2, test3

All of the file are pdfs.
I need to search for those files in a folder.
If I find *test1* at path *C:\Users\SOURCE* then copy it to my desktop folder *C:\Users\Destination*.

But it didn't copy any files from source -> destination folder.

```vb
Sub copyFile()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim strFileToCopy, strOldPath As String, strNewPath As String
  
    strOldPath = "C:\Users\SOURCE" 'Verzeichnis in dem die Datei liegt
    strNewPath = "C:\Users\Destination" 'Verzeichnis in welches kopiert werden soll
  
    With ActiveSheet
        strFileToCopy = .Range("A1") 'Zelle mit dem Namen
        strFileToCopy = strFileToCopy & ".pdf" 'Suffix anhängen
        If Dir(strOldPath & strFileToCopy, vbNormal) <> "" Then
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            objFSO.copyFile strOldPath & strFileToCopy, strNewPath & strFileToCopy
        End If
    End With
  
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Additional information:
the value in A1 is *test1*
the pdf file in the Source path is *test1.pdf*

Comment: Did you try stepping thru it while it runs to see each decision it makes? Is the problem the `If` statement?

Comment: Did you check if `strOldPath & strFileToCopy` returns a valid path? it looks like you are missing a slash so it should be `strOldPath & "\" & strFileToCopy`

Comment: Dear @Raymond Wu, the value in A1 = test1.pdf and the file name in the source folder is also "test1.pdf". After I changed the code to 'strOldPath & "\" & strFileToCopy' I receive an error "runtime error 53, file not found".  I checked the path, it is a valid path.

Comment: @braX yes, it seems the vba code doesn't execute that code line:  <code>Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      objFSO.copyFile strOldPath & strFileToCopy, strNewPath & strFileToCopy </code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't concatenate path manually. Use `FileSystemObject` (Windows only) methods instead.

```
Dim objFSO As Object, OldPath As String
...
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
OldPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strOldPath, strFileToCopy)
If objFSO.FileExists(OldPath) Then
  objFSO.copyFile OldPath, objFSO.BuildPath(strNewPath, strFileToCopy)
End If
...
```

Comment: thanks you very much for your approach!! This solved exactly my problem. Could you explain me a little bit why this method works? I wantto learn and improve my VBA skills.

Comment: but if the tool didn't find the file, how can I tell excel that it should copy the missing files in a new tab?

Comment: `FileSystemObject.BuildPath` method always returns valid file path for specified folder and path. Also `FileSystemObject.FileExists` is better than `Dir` for non-ASCII paths. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object

Comment: thanks for your help. how can I handle it, if I have many folders where I need to search of?

Comment: You can place folder list in array or [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) and search in a [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)